# ktor client multiplatform for raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ktor

Is there a chance to use ktor client (multiplatform) on a Raspberry Pi or is this platform not yet supported?

```
kotlin {
    linuxArm32Hfp("native") {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
                baseName = "example"
            }
        }
        compilations.main.cinterops {
            linuxCanInterop {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ??
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-curl:1.4.1")
    nativeMainImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-curl:1.4.1")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi is not supported by Ktor now. The main reason is that [kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines)
and [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) libraries don't support this platform too.